# App Engine, Python: setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin (or other headers) for static file responses

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a way to set custom headers of responses to static file requests?

E.g. I'd want to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` when serving static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  http_headers:
    X-Foo-Header: foo
    X-Bar-Header: bar value
```

Here is the documentation

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_Directory_Handlers

Comment: Sweet. Guess it wasn't there two years ago.

Comment: don't know if it was there 2 years ago, but it has a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

You can't; the only thing you can do is to stream these static files adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the Response.